# call to window.print not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In a asp.net content page I have a hyperlink and I am making call to window.print.. but its not working, not opening the print window.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print(); return false;" style="border:none" >
    <input type="image" src="print.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Post the code so we can determine if there are any syntax errors.

Comment: IE 9. Code: <a href="javascript:window.print(); return false;" style="border:none" > <input type="image" src="print.png" alt="" /></a>

Comment: What's the purpose of the input, couldn't you use an image instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *not* using javascript in the `href`.  Try this instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" style="border:none" >
    <input type="image" src="print.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Personally, I don't like adding any inline JavaScript to my elements.  So, I would do this:

CSS:

```css
#printPage{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input type="image" src="print.png" alt="" id="printPage" />
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('printPage').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.print();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/J5MBt/