# print preview mode after click on button not working for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J5MBt/) fiddle of print with print preview from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512375/call-to-window-print-not-working-in-ie) link. When i print using chrome it is going into a print preview mode. But when i try it on ie it is showing the print window right away. What I want to happened is when using ie and click print I will also go into a print preview mode.

This is the JS

```
document.getElementById('printPage').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.print();
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<input type="image" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="" id="printPage" />
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the links below?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303705/how-do-i-programatically-call-the-print-preview-screen-using-javascript-or-jqu

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/how-can-print-preview-be-called-from-javascript

Comment: no i haven't i will try to understand what is written in the answer. i have read it but i cant fully understand it